# how to append some string automatically with values in case of multiple updates in single row using trigger in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to append a text string with the value when an update is made on oracle table using trigger.

`if  old.v1 <> new.v1 then 
insert into table(v1, v2, v3) values(:new.v1 || 'This is new', :new.v2 , :new.v3)`

i am not able to record when multiple conditions are used. I have tried elsif and case statement but couldn't get through. Another condition suppose means there is `old.v2 <> new.v2`  so

`insert into table(v1, v2, v3) values(:new.v1 || 'This is new', :new.v2 || 'This is new' , :new.v3)`

This is cool if both the conditions are true while insert by using "or"operator. I want it to work if any one of them is true then to append the text string along with the required value automatically and in case of both conditions both updated values should append string and when condition is not true just record the value.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: What's the Database version? You can use calculated always column i nthe table itself: `<column_name> [<data_type>] [generated always] as (<column_expression>) [virtual]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `decode`.

```
 INSERT INTO yourtable
            (
               v1,
               v2,
               v3
            )
SELECT :new.v1 || DECODE( :OLD.v1 ,
                         :NEW.v1,'' ,
                        'This is new') ,
       :new.v2 || DECODE( :OLD.v2 ,
                         :NEW.v2 ,'' ,
                        'This is new') ,
       :new.v3 || DECODE( :OLD.v3 ,
                         :NEW.v3 ,'' ,
                        'This is new')
FROM   dual;
```

Comment: What's missing is the `IF UPDATING THEN ... END IF;`, as the user want this to happen on UPDATE only.

Comment: @g00dy : It could simply be a  `UPDATE ` trigger, in which case that wouldn't be required.

Comment: @g00dy  i thought of this later on which can be marked as a  solution a/q to me. I used multiple if else's. Like  `if  (old.v1 <> new.v1 and old.v2 <> new.v2 ) then insert into table(v1, v2, v3) values(:new.v1 || 'This is new', :new.v2 || 'This is new' , :new.v3) elsif (old.v1 <> new.v1) insert into table(v1, v2, v3) values(:new.v1 || 'This is new', :new.v2 , :new.v3) elsif elsif (old.v2 <> new.v2) insert into table(v1, v2, v3) values(:new.v1 , :new.v2 || 'This is new' , :new.v3)  end if;`   Thus inserting accordingly when the following conditions are true.